# How to read a memory mapped graph in android using tensorflow

Tags: android, tensorflow

First of all i have been searching for this for last 2 days and i was not able to find anything related to this other than this stackoverflow post - [How to read tensorflow memory mapped graph file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533264/how-to-read-tensorflow-memory-mapped-graph-file-in-android)

I have successfully build the tensorflow for android from its repo by following this link - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/

And i was able to integrate the detection functionality into my project using ClassifierActivity and was able to load and read a custom graph from that. I could read a retrained_graph.pb or a stripped_graph.pb and even a optimized_graph.pb using my app.

I used `bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:optimize_for_inference`

`bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:strip_unused`

commands to get optimized and stripped graphs (though the graphs are readily available from the server side).

But when using a memory mapped graph, i am getting an error that it could not read the graph.

From the above stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533264/how-to-read-tensorflow-memory-mapped-graph-file-in-android) i was sure that it can be done somehow. But i didnt find any help on net to get it done from android side.

Please feel free to guid me to some post or forums which can provide much info on how this can be done. I am not posting any code because i have followed the [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) of tensorflow android to make it work and i am stuck with this only.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

**Update**

Following is the error i am getting when i try to read memory mapped graph

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c, PID: 2632
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load model from 'file:///android_asset/optimized_mmapped_graph.pb'
    at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.<init>(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:100)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.TensorFlowImageClassifier.create(TensorFlowImageClassifier.java:109)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(ClassifierActivity.java:147)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.CameraActivity$3.onPreviewSizeChosen(CameraActivity.java:603)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.CameraConnectionFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(CameraConnectionFragment.java:425)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.CameraConnectionFragment.openCamera(CameraConnectionFragment.java:432)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.CameraConnectionFragment.access$000(CameraConnectionFragment.java:68)
    at nanob2c.nano.com.nanob2c.tensorflow.core.CameraConnectionFragment$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(CameraConnectionFragment.java:99)
    at android.view.TextureView.getHardwareLayer(TextureView.java:368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15175)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16204)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1195)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16204)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15198)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15193)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15971)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3610)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3400)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16204)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15198)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:282)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:288)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:323)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2461)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2094)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRo
```

Update - 23 May 2017

From Pete Warden's blogpost - https://petewarden.com/2016/09/27/tensorflow-for-mobile-poets/

it is clear that we can read the memmapped graph in mobile devices and its mentioned that - ***One thing to watch out for is that the file on disk is no longer a plain GraphDef protobuf, so if you try loading it into a program like label_image that expects one, you’ll see errors. You need to load the model file slightly differently, which we’ll show in the iOS example below.***

I am looking for an implementation of the same in android side.

Comment: Could you please post the error message and full stack trace?

Comment: @AllenLavoie i have added the error message and stack trace.

Comment: are you still doing it with bazel? You know they have now released gradle dependencies with prebuilt graphs .. not sure if it'll help

Comment: @Blundell can you provide me any valid reference for the gradle dependencies for this. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It was announced at IO you could look at there videos on YouTube, here it is in use: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/androidthings-imageclassifier/blob/master/imageclassifier-add-intelligence/app/build.gradle#L48

Comment: @Blundell Thank you so much..i will look into this..

Comment: @Blundell I tried the codelab project. Unfortunately it needs minSdkVersion 24 which is android N and we need to have support from 19.

Comment: having you tried reducing the min sdk and seeing what breaks? (i have a feeling not much .. or their camera impl which you can easily change)

Comment: Is the model in your APK? You can determine this via "unzip -v app.apk". If there is no "assets/optimized_mmapped_graph.pb" entry then that's your problem.

Comment: @AndrewHarp : yes the model is inside the assets folder. I confirmed it using the unzip command. :(

Comment: @Blundell : yes it also got fixed. But still it is not loading the memory mapped graph.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i checked in internet and with Pete Warden blog, the handling of memory mapped graph is not supported from the android side. Also the same is mentioned by MatPag as his answer.

But there should be some work around for this. As far as i searched we can tweak on to the JNI part and make it possible to handle the map from that side. My findings conclude with making changes on the following files can get a work around for this (i am not successful yet) -

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/native/tensor_jni.cc

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/native/graph_jni.cc

Also need to update the corresponding files on java part -

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/Tensor.java

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/java/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/NativeLibrary.java

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java

Will be updating the answer if i am successful with this.

Thank you all for providing valid information on this as all of this helped me a lot on searching for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

After performing some researches with your exception i've ended up 
[here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L370), to the method `loadGraph()` (which is the one crashing your application).

Seems that currently loading a memory mapped graph is not supported in the Android implementation you are using, in fact at line [#376](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L376) there is a TODO for the feature your are asking for (or at least it's something related)

Comment: I gave you a +1, which should cancel 5 -1's.